# Bootstrap Button drop-down should not hide when clicked inside

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a Button drop-down with some check-boxes inside it. One issue I am running into is if I click inside the drop down it goes hidden. I have to click again the button to bring the drop-down and see what I have checked.

I know it's default functionality of Bootstrap Button drop-down But How I can customize this so that it doesn't go away when I am selecting my check boxes.

Is there any safe jQuery way to customize this ? I am not very good with jQuery to solve this by myself. Any help will be much appreciable.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/prxv0yhq/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-group drop-down-multiselect">
                            <button type="button" class="btn  btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
                              <span class="fa fa-filter"></span>
                              Filter By
                              <span class="caret"></span> 
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                              <li>
                                <label>
                                  <input type="checkbox">
                                  Edited Date 
                                </label>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                <label>
                                  <input type="checkbox">
                                  Launched 
                                </label>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                <label>
                                  <input type="checkbox">
                                  Scheduled 
                                  </label>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                <label>
                                  <input type="checkbox">
                                  Planned 
                                </label>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prxv0yhq/2/

Comment: Is there any chance of having issues for using this event.stopPropagation(); ?

Like if I add any button inside this drop-down which open any popup , will that work for that ?

Comment: No, because is related only to this event.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/prxv0yhq/3/) I call a modal after changing any of the checkboxs.